# What are the various excuses which can be given to the manager while interviewing in office time?

Tags: interviewing, manager, time-management, time-off, break-time

I'm an experienced Software Engineer in India. My manager is a weird person and want all of his team to sit in front of PC all the time, despite having no work. He calls anyone anytime and if someone doesn't pick his call or reply to his email immediately, then he complain about that person to the director of organization. Even if someone writes on common team's group, that he isn't available for x minutes or is going for lunch, still he doesn't wait and calls that person.

My work timings are from 11 am-8:30 pm in this WFH environment. Nowadays, being frustrated from current company and its poor quality work, I have started interviewing a lot and many companies doesn't pick the time slot before 11 am or late night or weekends. So, I've to be continuously ready with new excuses which I an give to my manager in a hope that he won't call me.

Here are the ones which I've already tried:

- I am going outside to vaccinate me/mom/father/other family member.
- Just going outside for a walk (in evening)
- Having a headache. Needs 30-40 min break.
- Having upset stomach. Needs break.

Can anyone suggest some excuses?
Note: I take leaves only when interviewing for some big company so that I can focus on interview without any distraction.
PLEASE HELP AS I'M REALLY BAD AT LYING !!

Comment: Can you not tell the companies you're interviewing with: "I'm only available in these time brackets, can we please schedule the interview at one of these times?" You don't even need to specify it's because of your current job. I'd expect most interviewers to be familiar with the same problem you're having here, and be willing to work with you to find a time that suits everyone.

Comment: @Xono Yeah, exactly my thought as well. I'd personally be very careful with constantly trying to make excuses. If you do it too often, they'll know something is going on and they probably won't appreciate you lying to them. I'd just try to schedule the interviews outside working hours.

Comment: @Xono I have tried telling many companies about my available time slots but then they refuse to interview with me by saying sorry we can't interview you in these time slots and I don't want to lose that chance of grabbing a job.

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't be interviewing during work hours - you're being paid to work for that company - technically you should do it in lunch breaks, out of hours, or use booked vacation time. However, since the company expects you to work 9.5 hours a day and sounds bad in other ways, maybe this is a justifiable time to break that rule. On the other hand, if you don't answer when the boss calls, and the worst that can happen is that he complains about you to the leader of the organisation - so what? You're leaving soon anyway.

Comment: @BittermanAndy thanks for your suggestion. I want to change this organization because of low quality as well as low quantity of work. I'm not learning anything here. But yeah, I agree with this second part of your comment and I think I should stop caring too much about him.

Comment: One more issue is that if he doesn't like any subordinate because of whatever reason then he starts calling those employees to office. In my company, among all the employees, only he and 3/4 of his teams are working from office (apart from the Tech Support Hardware Team) even in this pandemic. I was luckier to be in the 4th team which was working from home. But he has warned many of us to follow his advice unless he will call us in office too. I am really scared of this as 2 members in his team who were going to office got Covid positive.

Comment: In my country it would be literally illegal to require a person to be available in their lunch break, or some other kind of break. It would also be illegal not to allow them to take lunch breaks and bathroom breaks.

Comment: Grow a spine. Lunch is your time, not anybody else's. I don't care if you're interviewing, or if you're just relaxing. Download an app that mutes your ringer during your lunch time. "many companies doesn't pick the time slot before 11 am" This is related to the same issue. Give them the time slots you have available, and that's it. If they can't interview you before 11 am or during your lunch time, then don't do the interview. Again, don't be such a pushover. It's ok to say 'no' sometimes. And if they really want you, they'll make the time.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have preserved vacation days for interviews in big companies. I think he will become more adamant and rude if I start taking regular vacations. In the past, it happened once that he cancelled my planned leave.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I know that lunch is my time. But the thing is that my manager treats his subordinates as his slave. And it has happened multiple times in the past that when someone is having lunch, he calls that person and wants him to be available immediately.

Answer (score 6):

You can say

> I had personal business to attend to.

No other explanation is necessary. And it's entirely true, so you don't have to lie.

If your boss is not too dense, he might realize it means you're interviewing elsewhere. If he is a bit less dense than that he might realize it means he should do something to encourage you to stay, rather than do more to make you want to leave.

Comment: Given the low level of professionalism, I'd expect OP's boss to explicitly ask "what business exactly?", to which an "It's private matter" reply may need to be well-rehearsed, and OP already claimed to be a bad liar.

Comment: @Mefitico, Yes that's a real problem. You have to be ready to stand firm on not explaining further. Or to give a response that implies it's something the boss won't want to know more about (for example that you were shopping for hemorrhoid cream or dealing with your child's diarrhea), but without exactly lying.

Comment: @Mefitico is right. He is like that. He has a habit of asking people about things.

Comment: Also, he doesn't behave in a way to let his employees stay. Since last year, 3 subordinates working under him resigned even without having another job offer in their hands. When they complained about him to the director of organization, then my manager showed a notebook to the director, which he has maintained covering all the negatives of every subordinate working under him. E.g. He has written like 6 months ago at 10 am, this subordinate didn't replied to my email within 20 minutes.

Comment: @WarWithSelf if the director accepted that as a valid complaint, why do you want to keep working there? That's a toxic organization. The only way they'll learn that's unacceptable is if enough people leave that they can't do their job.

Answer (score 3):

List of excuses:

- Internet went down.
- Phone was not charged.
- Mom wanted me for something.
- Was in the bathroom
- Did not see the message/call
- Decided to work outside
- Am sick for the day

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually most of interviews happens for 1 hour. So, for this duration, the internet down, laptop not charged will work. But rest of them will not work. As my manager expects his team to sit everytime in front of laptop. Also sick option is good but that would count as sick leave. I have saved/preserved this option while interviewing for really big companies.

Comment: You are planning on leaving. Why do you care how much sick leave you use up?

Comment: Yeah, I think I should start taking leaves.